# modal popup more than one window in the same webpage

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, styles

I have an two divs in my web page i am able to show one div as modal popup using styles how is it possible to show the other dive as modalpopup to the existing one.

Comment: what modal dialog plugin do you use?

Comment: @Manuel I am showing it as a modalpopup using styles for the div

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [css z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property to control the stack order of elements.

Also take a look at the JQuery plugin [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/). Here are some [examples](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples). Specifically take a look at the `Modal, Nested Modal` section.

From their site:

> jqModal is a plugin for jQuery to help you display notices, dialogs,
>   and modal windows in a web browser. It is flexible and tiny, akin to a
>   "Swiss Army Knife", and makes a great base as a general purpose
>   windowing framework.

Another JQuery plugin which may be of interest to you (if you create the modal dialogs yourself), is the [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#overview) plugin.